# How to implement drag and drop image only in canvas bounds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have implemented drag and drop functionality, but what I need right now is a functionality that will inactivate drag off Canvas.

When my picture in the top left corner one has coordinates x: 0, y: 0, but if a move to the left side of the coordinates go into minus (eg X: -1, -2 ... -100).

What I want to do is to not allow movement of the image outside Canvas.

Any ideas or even better piece of code is welcome

Comment: A piece of code would be welcome, please post yours.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much answered it. If the picture x position is, say, -2 just make it back to 0.

```
// Checks if the picture is beyond the x boundary's...
if (picture.x < 0) { 
    picture.x = 0; 
} else if ((picture.x + picture.width > canvas.width) {
    picture.x = canvas.width - picture.width;
}
```

same applies for the y axis.